# How to connect external hdfs to standalone Spark

Tags: security, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, kerberos

I am using 3 node Standalone Spark (1.6.0) cluster for my application.

Which is getting data from external Hadoop source. without hadoop authentication, application is working fine. but when i am going to enable kerberos security in my external hadoop cluster application is failing with this error.

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1398)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at
```

i didn't find out any implementation, how to configure kerberos in spark

**Edit:**
This is the code snippet that i have tried in spark-shell, in this code i am not using any spark api so it is working.

```
val config = new Configuration();
config.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://192.168.1.1:8020");
config.set("fs.file.impl", classOf[LocalFileSystem].getName());
config.set("fs.hdfs.impl", classOf[DistributedFileSystem].getName());
config.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "KERBEROS");
config.set("dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal.pattern","hdfs/*@TEST.COM");

println(UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled())

UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);
val ugi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI("hdfs/hadoop1.test.com@TEST.COM","/home/ubuntu/hdfs-hadoop1.keytab");

println(UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled())

ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction[String] {
    override def run(): String = {
        val fs = FileSystem.get(config).asInstanceOf[DistributedFileSystem];
        val path = new Path("hdfs://192.168.1.1:/test");
        fs.mkdirs(path);
        fs.close();
        "done"
    }
})
```

But when i am going to write dataframe in hdfs, it's giving me error.

```
ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction[String] {
    override def run(): String = {
        val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,"kaushal"),(2,"Mahendra"))).toDF("id","name")
        df1.saveAsParquetFile("hdfs://192.168.1.124:/test")
        "done"
    }
})
```

**Error:**

```
16/06/03 17:16:42 WARN Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name; Host Details : local host is: "ksp-machine/192.168.1.25"; destination host is: "hadoop2.bdbizviz.com":8020; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1398)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsParquetFile(DataFrame.scala:1837)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anon$1.run(<console>:46)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anon$1.run(<console>:42)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:54)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:56)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:58)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:60)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:62)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:64)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:66)
    at <init>(<console>:68)
    at .<init>(<console>:72)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:677)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1381)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.getServerPrincipal(SaslRpcClient.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.createSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1800(Client.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:716)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:712)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:711)
    ... 99 more
```

**Edit:**
Replaced above line from

```
val config = new Configuration();
```

to

```
val config = sc.hadoopConfiguration
```

Now when i am going to save the dataframe its creating the directory but there is not data and failing with different error.

```
Found ticket for hdfs/hadoop1.test.com@TEST.COM to go to krbtgt/TEST.COM@TEST.COM expiring on Sun Jun 05 18:00:17 IST 2016
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Found ticket for hdfs/hadoop1.test.com@TEST.COM to go to krbtgt/TEST.COM@TEST.COM expiring on Sun Jun 05 18:00:17 IST 2016
Found ticket for hdfs/hadoop1.test.com@TEST.COM to go to hdfs/hadoop1.test.com@TEST.COM expiring on Sun Jun 05 18:00:17 IST 2016
Found service ticket in the subjectTicket (hex) = 
0000: 61 82 01 70 30 82 01 6C   A0 03 02 01 05 A1 0E 1B  a..p0..l........

Client Principal = hdfs/hadoop1.test.com@TEST.COM
Server Principal = hdfs/hadoop1.test.com@TEST.COM
Session Key = EncryptionKey: keyType=18 keyBytes (hex dump)=
0000: E6 0E BE 73 5D 52 C6 20   38 3C 17 8E 67 9B D4 8E  ...s]R. 8<..g...
0010: 0D B9 29 B3 BB A8 91 7A   D9 40 61 15 9C 2A 92 22  ..)....z.@a..*."


Forwardable Ticket true
Forwarded Ticket false
Proxiable Ticket false
Proxy Ticket false
Postdated Ticket false
Renewable Ticket false
Initial Ticket false
Auth Time = Fri Jun 03 18:00:17 IST 2016
Start Time = Fri Jun 03 18:00:41 IST 2016
End Time = Sun Jun 05 18:00:17 IST 2016
Renew Till = null
Client Addresses  Null 
Krb5Context setting mySeqNumber to: 860698404
Created InitSecContextToken:
0000: 01 00 6E 82 02 76 30 82   02 72 A0 03 02 01 05 A1  ..n..v0..r......

Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_IN_PROCESS
Krb5Context setting peerSeqNumber to: 884037663
Krb5Context.unwrap: token=[05 04 01 ff 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 34 b1 58 1f 01 01 00 00 c7 f7 a2 76 14 87 50 0e b3 a2 71 bd ]
Krb5Context.unwrap: data=[01 01 00 00 ]
Krb5Context.wrap: data=[01 01 00 00 ]
Krb5Context.wrap: token=[05 04 00 ff 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 33 4d 37 24 01 01 00 00 f5 7d fb d2 38 60 d3 d2 30 a7 2b c7 ]
[Stage 0:>                                                         (0 + 3) / 30]16/06/03 18:01:04 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, ksp-machine): java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe; Host Details : local host is: "ksp-machine/192.168.1.5"; destination host is: "hadoop2.test.com":8020; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.create(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1600)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1465)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream$Writer.performIO(SocketOutputStream.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:117)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$3.run(Client.java:1013)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more

[Stage 0:>                                                         (0 + 5) / 30]16/06/03 18:01:04 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, ksp-machine): org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:784)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:176)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:160)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:289)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetRelation.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anon$3.newInstance(ParquetRelation.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.create(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1600)
    ... 26 more

[Stage 0:>                                                         (0 + 3) / 30]16/06/03 18:01:05 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
16/06/03 18:01:05 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting job.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 14, ksp-machine): org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:784)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:176)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:160)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:289)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetRelation.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anon$3.newInstance(ParquetRelation.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.create(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1600)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Logically it should be done with HadoopConf and injected in SparkContext

Comment: Thanks for comment, Can you please elaborate, how to set my kerberos principal and keytab file with spark

Comment: I don't use Kerberos, but SparkConf follows one logic, so actually, I have nothing more to add than what's already is these two posts http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#yarn-mode and http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/sg_spark_auth.html The last post is Cloudera documentation but it applies also to your use case.

Comment: According to document, I need to run my application in yarn model. is it not possible with standalone mode?

Comment: **Any Java or Scala client** can access a Kerberized HDFS, or a Kerberized HBase. Therefore a Spark executor can do it. What it requires is *(a)* a Kerberos login ("principal") and password ("keytab" file w/ encrypted pwd inside) *(b)* the Hadoop (or HBase) JARs and config files available for each executor *(c)* the "keytab" available for each executor -- take care of restricting access to that file! *(d)* **custom code** for creating explicitly a Hadoop `UserGroupInformation` using principal & keytab, before attempting to connect to HDFS.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I have deleted my answer. Unfortunately, documentation is misleading.

Comment: @eliasah, actually *no-one* is happy to deal with Kerberos, especially the guys who maintain the code base (cf. the in-famous GitBook *"Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate"*) and even "good" solutions may fail because of cryptic config issues that are a pain to debug; so I don't blame Cloudera to discourage people from trying - and getting burnt. Yes, it can be done, but you'd better have some experienced guys around to provide support.

Comment: Thanks for the info ! I think that your comment my provide a good wiki answer to the question.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I also tried with **custom code**, for normal operations its working, but when i am going for Spark operations, its failing.

Comment: OK, you also require *(x)* a **Kerberos conf file** with aaaaaaaaall the stuff required to communicate with the KDC -- compare your current `/etc/krb5.conf` versus what you have on the Hadoop cluster; the exception points to a missing entry for `[libdefaults] default_realm=<realm>` and/or `[domain_realm] <my_domain>=<realm>` mappings; but next you will have to fill `[realms] <realm> ={ kdc=<host> }` section accordingly.

Comment: And make sure that Kerberos conf file is present for all executors; if you cannot use the default location in `/etc`, use system property `java.security.krb5.conf` to point to your custom file.

Comment: I have already configured kerberos client in all machines with all the required changes. And i also tested with **kinit** command, i am able to get the ticket.

Comment: Also, make sure that Hadoop host names are DNS *canonical* names, otherwise Kerberos will suspect a security breach. Workaround would be to add Hadoop *alias* names in each `/etc/hosts` config.

Comment: OK, on closer examination it looks like a Hadoop config issue more than a Kerberos problem. Did you try to attach the Hadoop configuration the way it's always done, i.e. by dropping `core-site.xml`and `hdfs-site.xml` etc. in a local directory that is in your CLASSPATH *(like you would do with Log4J properties)*? Also, which flavor of Spark are you using, the Apache-with-Hadoop2.6 or the Apache-without-Hadoop-use-your-own-client or the CDH or the HDP?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I changed some code. now its able to create directory, but not creating any file inside it and failing with different error and also enabled debug for kerberos but no help.

Comment: "Hadoop alias names in each /etc/hosts config" is also correct.

Comment: Not sure what caused that `IOException: Broken pipe` (may require investigation of HDFS logs on the cluster) but `AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled` means that at some point the Hadoop property `hadoop.security.authentication` was not set to "kerberos" as expected. Unless the message is incoherent because of a buggy try/catch.